# Android Element similar to MAP ELEMENT in HTML

Tags: android

Is it possible to replicate the MAP element of HTML ( http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap ) in android. If so how ? I plan to put the touch event on the image and get the co ordinates of the place where the click happened. But I feel this is not a proper solution if the image is something like this

http://www.channel4.com/media/images/Channel4/c4-news/2014/March/27/27_solar_system_r_w.jpg

then it would be a problem for me.

Comment: Please replace the URL with an actual image URL. Right-click on the image and copy image URL.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to do this with a webview/html in your app or achieve the same result with java code?

Comment: @ruffles : I m trying to create an app with the image as the background of my imageview and when i click on any of the planets i plan to display information about that planet? All this will be done in android. Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

The question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312128/get-the-touch-position-inside-the-imageview-in-android/) is pretty much what you want, assuming your not trying to do it with html / webviews, and has a simple and straightforward answer that works.

Comment: yup i know about the solution u suggested but this would be a problem if my image is complex like the one in question . I m trying to create an app with the image as the background of my imageview and when i click on any of the planets i plan to display information about that planet? All this will be done in android. Is it possible