# Notification when a specific color from a pixel is selected

Tags: android, colors, touch, color-picker

I want to create a program that does this:

- take picture;
- select area to get color;
- the app will inform the user this is the current shade of white and select the shade based on the options we receive for the app

What I'm trying to do is to get a message to see if the selected color (from the touched position) is closer to a shade of white that I'm implementing (let's say, if the touched color is between #FCFFFFFF and #FCFEF9D5 the program will display "A2").

This is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


TextView touchedXY, invertedXY, imgSize, colorRGB;
ImageView imgSource1;
Button b, bOpenFromGallery;
static final int CAMREQUEST = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    touchedXY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xy);
    invertedXY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invertedxy);
    imgSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.size);
    colorRGB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorrgb);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    bOpenFromGallery = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_openFromGallery);
    imgSource1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.source1);





    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMREQUEST);

        }

    });

}

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMREQUEST) {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Bitmap newBitmap = BITMAP_RESIZER(bitmap, 1280, 768);


            imgSource1.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
            imgSource1.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);
        }
    }
}

OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener
        = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        float[] eventXY = new float[]{eventX, eventY};

        Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
        ((ImageView) view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

        invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
        int x = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[0]);
        int y = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[1]);

        touchedXY.setText(
                "touched position: "
                        + String.valueOf(eventX) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(eventY));
        invertedXY.setText(
                "touched position: "
                        + String.valueOf(x) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(y));

        Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();

        imgSize.setText(
                "drawable size: "
                        + String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth()) + " / "
                        + String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));

        //Limit x, y range within bitmap
        if (x < 0) {
            x = 0;
        } else if (x > (bitmap.getWidth() - 1)) {
            x = bitmap.getWidth() - 1;
        }

        if (y < 0) {
            y = 0;
        } else if (y > (bitmap.getHeight() - 1)) {
            y = bitmap.getHeight() - 1;
        }

        int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

        colorRGB.setText("touched color: " + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
        colorRGB.setTextColor(touchedRGB);

        return true;
    }
};

public Bitmap BITMAP_RESIZER(Bitmap bitmap,int newWidth,int newHeight) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);

    float ratioX = newWidth / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
    float ratioY = newHeight / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
    float middleX = newWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = newHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, middleX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    return scaledBitmap;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312423/4310784) said, you can get your image top-left corner, then calculate the touched position.
After that, u can get the color of that area by doing this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
```

you can filter color like this:

```
int red = Color.red(pixel);
int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
int green = Color.green(pixel);
```