# How to get click event from imageView in android

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

How to get click event position from VectorDrawable .xml file in image view.

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:clickable=true` and `android:onClick="methodName"` properties in the XML?

Comment: I have access .xml file from drawable folder and such file is .svg file but it convert into vectordrawable .xml. So I çan't get id of click event.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: use `View#setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener l)`

Comment: [This could help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312128/get-the-touch-position-inside-the-imageview-in-android)