# Imageview not following finger touch

Tags: android, touch-event, motionevent

I want to build an app that has an imageview and it simply follows the finger touch. In other words, the imageview follows the touch of the finger. I have partially achieved this, in the sense that the imageview is following the touch of the finger but the problem is that it is at some offset. The imageview is about an inch down the actual touch.

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_circle_black_24dp);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    img.setX(event.getX());
    img.setY(event.getY());
    return false;
}
```

}

What could be the reason behind the offset?

**Edit: Solution**

Following code does what I need:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView img;
    int[] viewCoords = new int[2];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_circle_black_24dp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        img.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);
        img.setX(event.getX()-(viewCoords[0]-img.getX()));
        img.setY(event.getY()-(viewCoords[1]-img.getY()));
        return true;

    }
}
```

Thanks to Doomsknight for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are using the X and Y coordinates of the touch event of the **Screen**.

And then drawing this coordinates on the X and Y of the **ImageView**.

This will cause the offset you are seeing, as they do not match up, as the imageview probably isnt at the very top of your screen.

What I think you are trying to do is get the X and Y, of the actual image. 
You will therefore need to offset the coordinates accordingly.

There is a good example of this already of getting the offset, and removing it: see link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312423/940834

> You can get the top left corner of your view as follows:
>
> ```
>  int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
>  imageView.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);
> ```
>
> From this and the touch
>      coordinates you can calculate the point inside the ImageView:
>
> ```
>  int touchX = (int) event.getX(); 
>  int touchY = (int) event.getY();
>
>  int imageX = touchX - viewCoords[0]; // viewCoords[0] is the X coordinate 
>  int imageY = touchY - viewCoords[1]; // viewCoords[1] is the y coordinate
> ```

Comment: After executing int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
 imageView.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords); the value in viewCoords is {0,0}. So, effectively, it does not do anything.

Comment: @ankitshubham. You have the reason for the offset in the answer above. If that particular implementation is not working I suggest looking for another on the internet now that you have a place to start.

Comment: @ankitshubham. Also I recommend putting this code in the ontouch method. Not the oncreate method. It may help as inflation should have occurred

Comment: Seems like I did solve my problem. Following logic did the trick:
        img.setX(event.getX()-(viewCoords[0]-img.getX()));
        img.setY(event.getY()-(viewCoords[1]-img.getY()));