# Android: Is there a way to check where on an ImageView the user has clicked?

Tags: android, imageview

Specifically, is there a way to get the coordinates of the user's click relative to the top-left point of the ImageView?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312128/get-the-touch-position-inside-the-imageview-in-android - refer the answer that provides for this question

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `onTouchListener` to get the co-ordinates as follows:

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       int x = (int) event.getX();
       int y = (int) event.getY();
});
```

Comment: Right, I understand. But does this give the x and y coordinates relative to the top-left of the entire screen or to the top-left of the View itself? I'm looking for the latter.

Comment: @Aryaman You can add on the top-left position of the `View v` screen coordinates if it was the screen position

Comment: @Aryaman getX() returns the touch point relative to the View