# How to get the touched point of an image view

Tags: android

[Shopping Flyer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DV3I.jpg) A viewpager contain a firebase image.This image contain many small different images.When I touch a small image I have to display  to another activity.how to proceed to achieve this ?

Comment: Please refer this link.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312128/get-the-touch-position-inside-the-imageview-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312128/get-the-touch-position-inside-the-imageview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use a GridLayout, with ImageView children. Use the onClickListener of the ImageView when they were added to the GridLayout to determine which image was clicked.

You don't need to know the coordinates of the image. Because the ImageView has its own space.

```
        GridLayout gridLayout;
        ArrayList<MyImage> myImages; // MyImage model should contain the image and information about the product

        for (MyImage myImage : myImages) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myImage.getImageBitmap());
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // start your details activity here

                }
            });
            gridLayout.addView(imageView);
        }
```

Comment: deal .for example I have say 30 shopping flyer,each page contain many products. user need to swipe from first to last page. if he found some interesting product he will touch and that should displayed in the next activity. so at same time it can be swipable whole page as well as clickable individual product.is it possible using grid layout?

Comment: Yeah, you can wrap it in a PagerView. Does the product have its own image or are there multiple product in a single image?

Comment: .yeah.all the individual product images will be uploaded to firebase for other purposes. my idea was getting the coordinates of the touched images and call the already uploaded images from firebase.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you that you don't need the coordinates of the image because the ImageView that contains it has its own click listener.

Comment: I think I have to clarify my question a little bit. please watch this video.https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10155985464981751&id=525001750

Comment: I can't see it. So you just want the x,y coordinate of the touch event?